# very slow processing and converting videos to m3u8 using ffmpeg library

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu, ffmpeg, m3u8

We are experiencing very slow processing and converting videos to m3u8 using ffmpeg library.

Note that the operating system used is Ubuntu Server and that the server has huge resources in RAM and CBU, and we noticed that the processing process does not consume the available resources significantly

Average video size: 1 GB
Average video processing time: 2 - 3 hours
The programming language used: asp.net core 3.1

We need to reach a maximum of 20 minutes in processing time, is that possible?

Comment: Do you have any concern about this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem does not seem to be related to programming. It is recommended to take the following steps to test, there should be some test results that can help you.

1. Use a local computer with a higher configuration of Ubuntu for testing, and it is recommended to install a solid state drive.
2. If the Ubuntu server you mentioned is a cloud server, it is recommended to upgrade to a higher performance for testing. It is best to test locally before deciding if such an upgrade is needed to save money.
3. If the above two points are difficult, for example, there is no such Ubuntu, we can also test it on a personal PC with Win 10/11 (with a solid state drive), install the ffmpeg environment, and then ensure that other software resources are closed, only Keep IIS, ffmpeg and other related services for testing.

I personally recommend trying the third suggestion first, so that you can get test results for the problem you care about. If the 1GB video can be processed within 20min, then we can consider upgrading the relevant configuration of Ubuntu.